# Reproject polygon from 3857 TO 4326 with R or QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, r, sf, epsg

I am trying to reproject a vector from EPSG:3857 to EPSG:4326. The data is originally available as an ArcRestful API [Canadian population tiles](https://services.arcgis.com/lGOekm0RsNxYnT3j/ArcGIS/rest/services/Populations_of_Canada_2016__10km_Gridded/FeatureServer/0)

When I bring in the layer into QGIS and save it out as a local file (gpkg, shp, or geojson) and select EPSG:4326 as the exporting projection the coordinates do not change:

```
Name:          cdn_tiles_4326
Path:          C:\Data\cdn_tiles_4326.geojson
Storage:       GeoJSON
Comment:

Encoding:      UTF-8
Geometry:      Polygon (MultiPolygon)
CRS:           EPSG:4326 - WGS 84 - Geographic
Extent:        -15730647.7283999994397163,5104289.3212999999523163 : -5842988.4855000004172325,18133920.6895000003278255
Unit:          degrees
Feature count: 106,623
```

Having the extents still in 3857 provides issues with geoprocessing (i.e. intersects).

I have tried this in both QGIS and R using sf::st_transforms()

Are there intermediate steps that need to be taken (i.e. to a different projection first, then to 4326), or is the a totally different approach?

Comment: Have you loaded the saved data into QGIS? What happens?

Comment: Yes I have...the output is what is in the original post. The data loads, the CRS is identified as 4326, but when I view the properties it shows the extents from 3857

Comment: But is it placed correctly?

Comment: That depends....on its own yes, but when you load other data (i.e. data with proper 4326 projection and coordinates) then no

Comment: the current GeoJSON standard allows only CRS 4326; using other CRS is not lege artis and may lead to issues (duh... obviously, or you would not be here). I don't have a sample of your data to test, but I suggest the following: 1) read it into R, 2) specify the CRS as 3857 via `sf::st_set_crs(yer_object, 3857)` 3) then, and only then, transform to 4326 via `sf::st_transform()`

Comment: Thanks for your comment....the data is listed as a link in the original post. I did get to work around the issue by reading the service in directly into R using the esri2sf package....but this does not resolve the reprojection issue I saw in QGIS....

Comment: @JindraLacko the current GeoJSON standard is not EPSG:4326.  The CRS of GeoJSON is http://www.opengis.net/def/crs/OGC/1.3/CRS84

Comment: @nmtoken I had the impression the current standard is this one https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7946#page-12 - of course I could be wrong...

Comment: @JindraLacko, you are correct that is the standard, now read it carefully and see if it mentions epsg:4326. It explicitly tells you the axis order is long/lat and gives a urn. I gave the URL equivalent. EPSG:4326 is lat/long

Comment: @nmtoken you are right and I got carried away. The standard is not referring to EPSG:4326. But it does clearly state that decimal degrees are the only allowed unit. Earlier versions of the standard allowed for other CRS, but it didn't quite work and it got removed. But you can still find metric GeoJSONs around. The hack with `sf::st_set_crs()` can help in R context.